# TVout 5.91 Library on Arduino mega 2560

Tags: arduino

I am trying to upload the example program for the tvOut i compiles properly adruino Uno but not for the Arduino Mega 2560. I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp: In member function 'void TVout::render_setup(uint8_t)':
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:729: error: '_VID_DDR' was not declared in this scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:729: error: '_VID_PIN' was not declared in this scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:730: error: '_SYNC_DDR' was not declared in this scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:730: error: '_SYNC_PIN' was not declared in this scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:731: error: '_VID_PORT' was not declared in this scope
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\TVout\TVout.cpp:732: error: '_SYNC_PORT' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Have you got a link to the library that you are using?

Comment: actually figured out the the libary is not configured to work with the Arduino mega. Therefore i tried to use the Beta file and it worked thank you for trying to help